# How do I scrape the word "Kentucky" from the whole page?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

Every time I run this code it only gives me the data three times but I know it pops up way more times on the page.

```
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import requests

   url = 'https://www.nba.com/players'
   result = requests.get(url)
   doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'lxml')
   college = doc.find_all(text='Kentucky')
   print(college)
```

Comment: Well, on that particular page the word *Kentucky* appears exactly three times. Try it CTRL+F and type *Kentucky*. What exactly you'd like the final output to be?

Comment: well there's on this website im using they have a the whole list of players on one page at least thats what it looks like but now that im thinking about it it might just be loading as I scroll and if thats the case how would I get access to those?

Comment: maybe I can get all the information from the page then extract "kentucky" from my own data folder?

Answer (score 0):

It is because find_all with text will search for **exact text match**.

```py
college = doc.find_all(text='Kentucky')
```

**Valid one:** `<option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>`.
**No valid:** `<option value="Western Kentucky">Western Kentucky</option>`.

If you want to find all occurrences you need to use **regular expressions**.
Check [beautiful-soup-doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument). Also use **string** instead of **text**.

```
The string argument is new in Beautiful Soup 4.4.0.
In earlier versions it was called text:
```

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.nba.com/players'
result = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'lxml')
college = doc.find_all(string=re.compile("Kentucky"))
print("Total elements: " + str(len(college)))
print(college)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Total elements: 6
['Kentucky', 'Western Kentucky', 'Kentucky', 'Western Kentucky', 'Kentucky', '{"props":{"pageProps":{"la
```

Comment: thank you this is great to know as well but I actually was looking for specifically Kentucky players, do you know how I can achieve that?

Comment: @MormanDSingles you question was about just word "Kentucky" and I think I answered you question correctly. If you want to ask another question, create a new one.